# Extracting data from a .DLL: unknown file offsets

Tags: dll, extract, offset

I'm currently trying to extract some data from a .DLL library - I've figured out the file structure (there are 1039 data blocks compressed with zlib, starting at offset 0x3c00, the last one being the fat table). The fat table itself is divided into 1038 "blocks" (8 bytes + a base64 encoded string - the filename). As far as I've seen, byte 5 is the length of the filename.

My problem is that I can't seem to understand what bytes 1-4 are used for: my first guess was that they were an offset to locate the file block inside the .DLL (mainly because the values are increasing throughout the table), but for instance, in this case, the first "block" is:

1. Supposed offset: 2E 78 00 00
2. Filename length: 30 00 00 00
3. Base64 encoded filename: 59 6D 46 30 64 47 78 6C 58 32 6C 75 64 47 56 79 5A 6D 46 6A 5A 56 78 42 59 33 52 70 64 6D 56 51 5A 58 4A 72 63 31 4E 6F 62 33 63 75 59 77 3D 3D

yet, as I said earlier, the block itself is at 0x3c00, so things don't match. Same goes for the second block (starting at 0x3f0b, whereas the table supposed offset is 0x167e)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question lol

Anyway, those numbers *are* the actual offsets of the file blocks, except for the fact that the first one starts from some random number instead than from the actual location of the first block. Aside from that, though, differences between each couple of offsets do match the length of the corresponding block.